# Java background changes when click on draw area

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, click

before this i have problem change color of pen and background color when using color picker.. now color pen can be changed but the background cannt change color. It can change background color but i need to click over the draw area then the background will change.. it should be changed background color when we selecting our color right? but it didnt..

ButtonPanel

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import java.awt.Color;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ItemListener,
    ActionListener
{
    private DrawingArea drawingArea;

        private String tools[] = {"Pencil", "Line", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Filled Circle", "Filled Rectangle", "Round Rectangle", "Filled Round Rectangle"};

        private Color color = (Color.WHITE);
        private JComboBox<String> jcbTool;
    private JButton btnClear;
        private JButton save;
        private JButton infobutton;
        private JButton colorBtn;
        private JButton colorBg;



    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
    {
                if (ie.getSource()==jcbTool)

            {       

                String tool = (String)jcbTool.getSelectedItem();
                drawingArea.setTool(tool);

        }
             //  else  
                //    if (ie.getSource()==eraser)
//{               String tool = (String)eraser.getSelectedItem();
 //              drawingArea.setTool(tool)
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource()==btnClear)
            drawingArea.clear();     
                else if (e.getSource()==infobutton)
                {
            //default title and icon
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Paint java created by bla bla bla bla bla blaa");
                }
                else if  (e.getSource()==colorBtn)
                {
                    color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"LOL",color);
                    drawingArea.setColorBtn(color);
                }
                  else if  (e.getSource()==colorBg)
                  {
                    color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"LOL",color);
                   drawingArea.setColorBg(color);
                  }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `repaint()` method in your `actionPerformed()` method in `DrawingArea` :

```
if (e.getSource() == colorBg) {
    color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "LOL", color);
    drawingArea.setColorBg(color);
    drawingArea.repaint();
}
```

because when you change brush color and click mouse `repaint()` method fired,

but when you set background color you need to force repaint also.

Comment: Oh my it's works.. U solved my question.. Thankx.. just a bit mistake and missing there . Really appreciate your help. Thank alot

Comment: Actually, he didn't even "set the background color"; all he did after the color was chosen was to set a variable named `colorBg` in `DrawingArea`, which didn't have an effect since `paintComponent()` wasn't called.

Comment: hmm i thought that by drawingArea.setColorBg(color) and it going to set the color of bg.. and i really didnt notice that repaint is part of function that needed to perform this change..

Comment: as @ajb mentioned you only change color(inctance variable), but it will change color of panel when you refill it with a new color in `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: yea i getting weird when the background only changed when i mouse click on the drawingarea.. and i really curious said that i wont related with mousePressed.. oh yea actually there;s another problem that in occur in that code its about save button.. i already removed some coding at above to avoid some case.. should repost new question?